# Object property name changes when parsing it to node js

Tags: ajax, node.js

I have an object:

`{"description":"Κλείσε τις βάνες","closeValves":["13/21","12/31","13/12","12/32"]}`

and when i am sending it to node js with ajax the moment it gets into the `router.post` it transforms into this

`{"description":"Κλείσε τις βάνες","closeValves[]":["13/21","12/31","13/12","12/32"]}` ..

Any ideas why this is happening? in the node script where i have the `router.post` i am requiring this

`let express = require('express');
 let router = express.Router();`

**Update at comment:**
the call the function:

```
formEvent(json,'events/entry',valvescallback);
```

and the function AJAX:

```
function formEvent(data,module,next,e){//the request function
    e=e||false;

    console.log("form:",data)
    if( e ){e.preventDefault();}
    var url = './'+module; // the script where you handle the form input.

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        data: data,
        dataType:'json',
        success: function (data) {
            next(data);
        },
        error:function (data) {
            next(data)
        }
   });
}
```

**Update at comment 2:**

No the data come from postgress SQL in a text type column like this

`{"description":"Κλείσε τις βάνες","closeValves":["13/21","12/31","13/12","12/32"]}`

and i am using this to transform it into json and parse it:

```
var json = jQuery.parseJSON(data.task);
json.action = 'getValves';
json.test = json.closeValves;//test to see if it also changes name
```

I can see that it transformes any property that is an array like this 
`name:[1,2,3] --> name[]:[1,2,3]`

the odd is that when I am `console.log` the data inside the AJAX function the are in the right form but inside the post they change..

Comment: post the AJAX function.

Comment: Is the data coming from a form?

Comment: Add the html form if you are using it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it!! the answer is at the definition of the `body-parser` npm usage:

`app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false}));`

you just need to make the extended property true and the array name will not change.. so the answer is

`app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true}));`